# Javascript C3 chart generate shift chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, axis-labels, c3.js, axes

I'm using C3js chart to generate a shift chart as below:

[image]

Here is the my data format:

```
var dataItems = [
{
  "title": "2017/02/04",
  "shifts": [
    {
      "startTime": "05:30:00",
      "endTime": "05:30:00",
      "items": [
        {
          "quantities": {
            "itemA": 600       
           }        
        },
        {
          "quantities": {
            "itemB": 400   
           }    
        },{
          "quantities": {
            "itemC": 500      
           }                                 
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "2017/04/04",
  "shifts": [
    {
      "startTime": "05:30:00",
      "endTime": "05:30:00",
      "items": [
        {
          "quantities": {
            "itemA": 720     
           }          
        },
        {
          "quantities": {
            "itemB": 1000   
           }    
        },{
          "quantities": {
            "itemC": 850     
           }                                  
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "2017/05/04",
  "shifts": [
    {
      "startTime": "05:30:00",
      "endTime": "05:30:00",
      "items": [
        {
          "quantities": {
            "itemA": 450    
           }           
        },
        {
          "quantities": {
            "itemB": 800   
           }    
        },{
          "quantities": {
            "itemC": 1000   
           }                               
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
];
```

I have tried a similar example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2lose/rg082b19/144/). but it doesn't work well.
Ideas i want to create a bar chart like with xAxis format like the image.

Could someone can suggest me about the data or an example like the shift charts above?

Thanks,

Comment: Found an example same on what i looking for using d3 on [codepen](https://codepen.io/idan/pen/xejuD?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Your code for tuning x-axis labels position is correct.
Just put it into function and call when chart is drawn.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/xey6xuf2/2/) or this snippet:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    ...
    onrendered: pushTheYearsDown,
    onresized: pushTheYearsDown
});
```

and

```
// push the years down
function pushTheYearsDown() {
  d3.selectAll('#chart .tick text tspan')[0].forEach(function (d) {
      var tspan = d3.select(d);
      if (!isNaN(Number(tspan.text())))
          tspan.attr('dy', '2em')
      else 
          tspan.attr('dy', '0.5em')
  });
}
```

Comment: Its not just push the year down, i mean with the example data series and the image, how can i generate x-axis separate by day?